# How to display warning message in InfoPath

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, infopath-rules, infopath-form

I have two list boxes. When I select the different values from them, a alert message should appear and when I click OK , the alert message should disappear.

Please suggest the way to achieve the above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are dependent on a combination of two drop-down list boxes but here's one way.

Create a small section called AlertSection and add your alert text and a button that is labeled "Close". 
Create a section at the bottom of the form that is hidden with a format rule and call it HiddenSection.

I am assuming 3 fields not in the AlertSection.  ddlField1, ddlField2, txtField (this goes in the hidden section)

Create an Action rule on the button, when clicked, set the txtField in the hidden section to 1.

Create 4 rules on the alert section.

1. ddlField1 is blank then hide the section
2. ddlField1 = ValueA then hide this control
3. ddlField2 = ValueC then hide this control
4. txtField in the hidden section = 1 then hide this control

Try this in a test form first to check the logic.  You may be able to concatenate some of these, but separating the rules is often easier to read and troubleshoot later.